# Communicate between two directives Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to communicate between two directives. I tried the service way, it didn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

```
<list-data testing="trial" template-url="grid.html" link-passed="data.json"></list-data>
```

My directive and service:

```
app.directive('listData', function($http, serVice){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        testing: '@',
        linkPassed: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
        return attrs.templateUrl || 'some/path/default.html'
    },
    link: function($scope){
        var url = 'js/' + $scope.linkPassed;
        $http.get(url).then(success, error);

        function success(data){
            $scope.iconUrl = data.data;
        }

        function error(response){
            console.log(response)
        }

        $scope.tryingToClick = function(icon){
            serVice=icon.name;
            console.log(serVice)
        }
    }
};
});

app.directive('render', function(serVice){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '{{rendering}}',
        link: function($scope){
            $scope.rendering = serVice.name;
            console.log(serVice)
        }
    };
});

app.factory('serVice', function(){
    return{items:{}};
})
```

grid.html is just a simple grid layout where I am trying to show the data in grid.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 grid" ng-repeat="icon in iconUrl">
<p ng-click="tryingToClick(icon)">{{icon.iconUrl}}</p> 
</div>
```

I need to pass the data when I click the function tryingToClick and the icon passes to the render directive. I cannot use $rootscope here, nor make new controllers. I will be using the logic here in a pretty big enterprise app, just that I made a very simple version of it on my localhost, just to get the logic right.

Answer (score 0):

Your service doesn't look quite right. I'd use

```
app.factory('serVice', function() {

  var settings = {};

  // optionally set any defaults here
  //settings.name = 'me';

  return settings;
});
```

and you're not setting the name property of the service here:

```
serVice=icon.name;
```

It should be

```
serVice.name = icon.name;
```

given that you're looking for the `name` property later: `$scope.rendering = serVice.name;`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by not creating more controllers? Do you mean that you can't create more on the app or that you can't use controllers within the directives?

From what I understood of your question I threw this codepen together for experimentation http://codepen.io/ihinckle/pen/JWGpQj?editors=1010

```
<div ng-app="directiveShare">
    <directive-a an-array="[1,2,3,4,5]"></directive-a>
    <directive-b></directive-b>
</div>

angular.module('directiveShare', [])
.directive('directiveA', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            anArray: '<'
        },
        controller: function($scope, aService){
            $scope.clicked = aService.setIcon;
        },
        template: `
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in anArray" ng-click="clicked(item)">item</li>
            </ul>`
    }
})
.directive('directiveB', function(){
    return {
        controller: function($scope, aService){
            $scope.displayIcon = aService.getIcon;
        },
        template: `
            <h1>{{displayIcon()}}</h1>
            `
    }
})
.factory('aService', function(){
    var srvc = {};

    srvc.setIcon = function(x){
        srvc.icon = x;
    };

    srvc.getIcon = function(){
        if(srvc.icon){
            return srvc.icon;
        }else {
            return '';
        }
    };

    return srvc;
});
```

I used getters and setters in the service and controllers on the directives to expose the functions.